# How can i ensure the sticky behavior of my html table is not altered by the color of the background?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have sticky table thead with 2 rows of headers. The colour of the background for `thead` has to be white so I can keep the sticky behaviour but the background is covering the border of the rows.

How can I make the border appear over the background ?

```css
.table-responsive {
  height: 500px;
}

thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background: white; 
/*   removing background color allow border to appear (though not perfectly) but then the sticky behavior doesn't quite work */
  z-index: 3;
}

.sticky-col-top {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  max-width: 6em;
  min-width: 6em;
  background: white;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  z-index: 3;
}

.weekday-row {
  border-top: 3px solid #E2E2E2;
}

.sticky-col {
    position: sticky;
    left: 0px;
    width: 6em;
    background: white;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    z-index: 2;
}

td:nth-child(even),
th:not(.days):nth-child(even) {
  background: #F7F7F7;
}

.days {
  color: #606060;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="table-responsive">

  <table class="table calendar">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col-top"></th>
        <th class="days">1</th>
        <th class="days">2</th>
        <th class="days">3</th>
        <th class="days">4</th>
        <th class="days">5</th>
        <th class="days">6</th>
        <th class="days">7</th>
        <th class="days">8</th>
        <th class="days">9</th>
        <th class="days">10</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col-top"></th>
        <th class="weekday-row">M</th>
        <th class="weekday-row">T</th>
        <th class="weekday-row">W</th>
        <th class="weekday-row">T</th>
        <th class="weekday-row">F</th>
        <th class="weekday-row">S</th>
        <th class="weekday-row">S</th>
        <th class="weekday-row">M</th>
        <th class="weekday-row">T</th>
        <th class="weekday-row">W</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table-body">
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 1</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 2</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 3</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 4</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 5</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 6</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 7</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 8</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 9</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 10</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
```

The js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/base_kh/t59xrjw6/13/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to do it with border.
But you can mimic border using pseudo-elements `::after` and `::before`:

First: remove default bootstrap border:

```
.table tbody td, .table tbody th {
  border: none;
}
```

Then add position relative to table row:

```
.table tbody tr {
  position: relative;
}
```

And now, add pseudo-element:

```
.table tbody tr::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';

  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #dee2e6;

  position: absolute;

  z-index: 4;
}
```

Result:

```css
.table-responsive {
  height: 500px;
}

thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background: white; 
/*   removing background color allow border to appear (though not perfectly) but then the sticky behavior doesn't quite work */
  z-index: 3;
}

.sticky-col-top {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  max-width: 6em;
  min-width: 6em;
  background: white;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  z-index: 3;
}

.weekday-row {
  border-top: 3px solid #E2E2E2;
}

.sticky-col {
    position: sticky;
    left: 0px;
    width: 6em;
    background: white;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.table tbody td, .table tbody th {
  border: none;
}

.table tbody tr {
  position: relative;
}

.table tbody tr::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';

  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #dee2e6;

  position: absolute;
  
  z-index: 4;
}

td:nth-child(even),
th:not(.days):nth-child(even) {
  background: #F7F7F7;
}

.days {
  color: #606060;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="table-responsive">

  <table class="table calendar">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col-top"></th>
        <th class="days">1</th>
        <th class="days">2</th>
        <th class="days">3</th>
        <th class="days">4</th>
        <th class="days">5</th>
        <th class="days">6</th>
        <th class="days">7</th>
        <th class="days">8</th>
        <th class="days">9</th>
        <th class="days">10</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col-top"></th>
        <th class="weekday-row">M</th>
        <th class="weekday-row">T</th>
        <th class="weekday-row">W</th>
        <th class="weekday-row">T</th>
        <th class="weekday-row">F</th>
        <th class="weekday-row">S</th>
        <th class="weekday-row">S</th>
        <th class="weekday-row">M</th>
        <th class="weekday-row">T</th>
        <th class="weekday-row">W</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table-body">
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 1</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 2</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 3</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 4</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 5</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 6</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 7</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 8</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 9</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 10</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
```

Comment: Hi M51, thank you for your answer ! The behaviour I am trying to get is to keep showing borders between all the rows (except the top border for the row with days), with the class weekday-row's top row always visible. Your answer put me on the right track though, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Applying the pseudo element `::before` on the headers did the trick, thanks @m51 for giving me the crucial clues !

All I needed was to add the below to my css:

```
th {
  position: relative;
}

.sticky-border th::before{
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
}
```

and the js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/base_kh/t59xrjw6/22/

Comment: If you find m51 answer valuable, you could upvote it (clicking the upward pointing arrow in his answer)